# Power BI embed URL stopped working after upgrading the user account to PRO license

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

We are trying to load the Power Bi report embedded in an angular application using Website or portal Power BI Embed URLs,

The user account with which we get the access tokens was having a free license and was working till last week. But then the free license got expired and the power bi dashboard was not loading. Afterwards We upgraded the license of the user account to PRO license now but still the report was not loading. Now when tried to access the report using Sharepoint Online Urls, the reports are loading in angular application.

What could be the possibilities that it stopped working for Website or portal Urls? The workspace is having Power BI premium capacity license as well.

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: There is no error message . It is redirecting to Login Page.

Answer (score 3):

1. Try generating the Secure Embed code again and test that in your code.

   If this doesn't work then:
2. Reach out to the support team here with the repro steps and request id.
   To get the request id, follow below steps:

   1. Open Network tab in browser console
   2. Reload the page in which the report is getting embedded
   3. Look for the below request and find RequestId in Response Headers section as shown in the image
      https://wabi-india-central-a-primary-redirect.analysis.windows.net/explore/reports/db85dad7-7bcb-4ecc-b8be-d4b829515ef1/modelsAndExploration?preferReadOnlySession=true
      [image: RequestId]